# how do I create bricks in an object with geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, logic-bricks

[image]

I want to create a brickwork repeating an object (arbitrary shape) with the correct layout. How can this be done? thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

How can I create another row of bricks? and make the seams the same when changing the size of the brick?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this: [image]

you will get this:

[image]

I hope that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. everything worked out, but how else can you create a row of bricks on the side?

Comment: Hey Andrey, pls don't ask additional questions in comments. Just open a new question. You can open as many questions as you like. thx.